# put Images/icons before asp:label

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, icons, label

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Year" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_Year") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Transmission" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_Transmission") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="FuelType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_FuelType") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Millage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_Millege") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="DateCreated" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_Created") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad_Price") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                </b>
                            </div>
```

this is my code. I want to add image/icon of year,millage,fuel type and all before them. Kindly tell me how to do that.[This is how it is looking like. I want to show icon before them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxvq2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your labels in a table, like in the following example (having 1 row / tr per label and icon)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img url='SomeIcon.png' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img url='SomeIcon2.png' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    ...

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Divs, as it will be more responsible:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img width="200" heigth="200px" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/ae/55/e6ae554a65f4dd2f92b0f737001fea83.jpg" alt="">

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div>
        <strong>Car</strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Model</strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Engine</strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Tires</strong>
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Etc</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```